# Issue time converting to 24 hours when i write time on asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, c#-5.0

I working on with C# and ASP.NET webforms using Visual Studio 2022. I have an issue when trying to write time to a textbox.

When I try to write time `11:30 pm` to a textbox, it is converted automatically to 23:30 - why was it converted?

I need time to working on 12 hours mode exactly as I write it.

So if I write `11:30 am`, it must be shown as `11:30 am`.

`11:30 pm` must be shown as `11:30 pm` - here I have the issue that it is converted to `23:30 pm`.

Expected result:

- when I write `11:30 pm`, it must show `11:30 pm`

What do I do to solve this issue please?

webpage.cs

```
protected void txtFromTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var Transactiondate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
        var dateonly = Transactiondate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
       var eventDate = txtDate.Text + " " +Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromTime.Text).ToString("HH:mm");
      
        Label1.Text = eventDate.ToString();
}
```

web page.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Date" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" AutoPostBack = "True" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFromTime" runat="server" Text="FromTime"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromTime" runat="server" TextMode="Time" AutoPostBack = "True"  OnTextChanged="txtFromTime_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

picture issue

[image: Image for issue time]

Comment: take a look at [this datetime format guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  You are using `HH`, you want `hh`

Comment: IMHO you should just use the "g" format - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#GeneralDateShortTime

Comment: `Label1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).Add(Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromTime.Text).TimeOfDay).ToString("g");`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PEReBf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you used upper-case `HH` instead of lower-case `hh` in the format string. You also need the AM/PM indicator:

```
hh:mm tt
```

This is well-documented:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Unfortunately, right now this always results in an uppercase indicator, so you'll see `11:30 PM`. If you really need to see `11:30 pm` you need to correct it with normal string manipulation.

I'd like to see the `t` ("t"ime of day) specifiers enhanced, such that lowercase `t` is a lowercase indicator and uppercase `T` is an uppercase indicator, along with a mechanism to infer the case from the system's datetime format. I suspect the reason this has not happened is a certain important time format uses a literal `T` to separate the date and time portions of the string.

Answer (score 1):

why not consider just one text box, and use textmode=

So, say this text box:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
            TextMode="DateTimeLocal">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

You then get/see this:

[image]

In other words, you have one text box - it will have both date and time for you.

About the only thing I don't like, is tab key does not select, you have to hit enter key.

but, it also allows in-line editing if you don't want to use the picker.

Hence this:

[image]

And if you enter (without the picker), then you have to use arrow keys to move to the next part. Again, I don't find this 100% intuitive.

However, you can drop in 2 controls, and feed it the "one" date time variable. You feed using "iso" date format, but it will take on your local settings.

So, say this markup:

```
        <h4>Enter Date</h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"
            TextMode="Date">
        </asp:TextBox>

        <h4>Enter Time</h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTime" runat="server"
            TextMode="Time">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

And code to load:

```
            DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;

            txtDate.Text = dtStart.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd");
            txtTime.Text = dtStart.ToString(@"HH:mm");
```

NOTE close above, I feed the time a 24 hour format, but it does display in 12 hour format.

and now we get/see this:

[image]